# Text doesn't show when screen is under 576 px

Tags: html, css

Text moves to far right when the screen is lower than 576 pixels.

css:

```
.row
{
display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;

}
```

html

```
div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical mg1rem raleway">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Registrations</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Scramble</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Results</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  <h1 class="abel"><u>Group Comp'23</u></h1>
    </div>
```

I have tried overflow:visible but it also doesn't work.

Comment: which text are you referring to? Please include a [mre] of the issue you want help with.  Also read the [ask] page for more tips

Comment: flex-wrap:nowrap; is causing the issue , when you shrink that much it prevents the flex items from wrapping onto new lines , causing them to stay in single line

Comment: You have to remove flex-wrap: nowrap from the css .row.

Comment: I want it in a single line tho @noob